# Solving for v_out in a non-ideal difference op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up the KCL equations for this op amp.  Everything I've tried seems to lead to a dead end.  I've tried setting up three KCL equations at nodes v_n(-), v_p(+), and V_out, and using just node -v_d and v_out.  Anyone have any ideas?

This is what I've tried using \$-v_d\$ as a node:  \$\frac{-v_d - v_2}{R} + \frac{-v_d - v_{out}}{R}+\frac{-v_d}{R_i}=0\$ and \$\frac{v_d-v_1}{R}+\frac{v_d}{R}+\frac{v_d}{R_i} = 0\$ and \$\frac{V_{out}+v_d}{R}+\frac{V_{out}-Av_d}{R_o} = 0\$ but this seems to be trivial as the first and second equation reduce to something that doesn't involve other parts of the circuit.

Comment: Show us your equations, and we'll point out where you've gone wrong.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Edited to include what I've done.

Comment: \$v_d\$ is not ground referenced.  This makes things tough.  I suggest representing this without that variable.  \$v_d\$ is then simply the current through \$R_i\$ times  \$R_i\$

Comment: .. then \$v_-\$ is just \$v_+\$ plus the voltage across \$R_i\$

Comment: @ScottSeidman So you're saying:  \$\frac{v_{-} - v_2}{R} + \frac{v_{-} - v_{out}}{R}+\frac{v_{-}-v_{+}}{R_i}=0\$ and \$\frac{v_{+}-v_1}{R}+\frac{v_{+}}{R}+\frac{v_{+}-v_{-}}{R_i} = 0\$ and \$\frac{V_{out}-v_{-}}{R}+\frac{v_{out}-A(v_{+}-v_{-})}{R_o} = 0\$, where \$v_d = v_{+} - v_{-}\$?

Comment: No.  Your third term in the first equation would be \$(v_- - v_+)/R_i\$;  similar for the other equations

Comment: @ScottSeidman So \$v_d=iR_i\$ where \$i\$ is the input bias current that depends on the op amp?

Comment: Yes, you have it now, though I think its actually \$-iR_i\$ with your sign conventions.

Comment: Why would it be \$-iR\$?  If the bias current enters through \$v_{+}\$ and leaves through \$v_{-}\$ why isn't it positive?

Comment: it depends entirely on the direction you assign to \$i\$.

Answer (score 1):

There are only three nodes where the voltages are not already determined. So, three equations are needed.

Non-inverting input:
$$
\frac{\text{Vp}-\text{V1}}{R}+\frac{\text{Vp}}{R}+\frac{\text{Vp}-\text{Vn}}{\text{Ri}}=0 
$$
Inverting input:
$$
\frac{\text{Vn}-\text{V2}}{R}+\frac{\text{Vn}-\text{Vout}}{R}+\frac{\text{Vn}-\text{Vp}}{\text{Ri}}=0
$$
And the output:
$$
\frac{\text{Vout}-A (\text{Vp}-\text{Vn})}{\text{Ro}}+\frac{\text{Vout}-\text{Vn}}{R}+\frac{\text{Vout}}{\text{RL}}=0
$$
Using a computer algebra program to solve this system yields
$$
\text{Vout} = \frac{\text{RL} (2 A R \text{Ri} (\text{V1}-\text{V2})+\text{Ro} (R (\text{V1}+\text{V2})+2 \text{Ri} \text{V2}))}{R (2 \text{Ri} ((A+2) \text{RL}+2 \text{Ro})+3 \text{RL} \text{Ro})+4 R^2 (\text{RL}+\text{Ro})+2 \text{Ri} \text{RL} \text{Ro}}
$$

This reduces to Vout = $V1-V2$ for \$Ro = 0\$ and \$Ri = \infty\$